# How do I configure Log4j2 to delete the files after X days

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a specific request for Log4j2. Our setup is running on Java 6 and cannot upgrade for the time being. Hence the highest version of Log4j2 I could use is 2.3.x which I have. I would like to have the log files deleted after X number of days using Log4j2 configuration. Is there any possibility directly or by writing a custom handler?

What I have now:

```
   <Properties>
    ...
    <Property name="PAYLOADfilename">${sys:com.x.payload.logfile}    </Property>
   </Properties>
   <Appenders>
            ...    
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="PAYLOAD" fileName="${PAYLOADfilename}" filePattern="${PAYLOADfilename}_%d{ddMMyyyy}_%i">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>[%d] %p %c{1} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="99"/>
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>      
        </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
...
</Loggers>
```

Comment: @sazzad I have updated the question with the current config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RollingFileAppander](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-2-rollingfileappender-example/) class from the library and configure it to retain backup of particular amount days.

You can refer example snippet I've attached from my environment:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.R.File=console.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=15
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Here I am taking backup for last 15 days, you can configure it as per your requirement.

Note: Reply here if you need more understanding.

Comment: OP specifically asked about Log4j2. Though your provided link is about Log4j2, your example is of Log4j (1).

Comment: @sazzad apologies for that, what should I do now? I'm new here.

Comment: You can do a lot of things. Just try to keep your *help* helpful :)

Comment: Will this not make it maximum 15 logs, I do not need one log per day. I might need a log every hour but only delete after X (5) days.

Comment: Also as @sazzad says I need a fix in Log4j2.